# PHP. How to assign current date and time to an input field

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

How to assign default value current time stamp to an input field.

Then I want to insert into db as hidden.

How can I assign a default value (current taimestamp)?

```
<input name="status" id="status" type="hidden" 
value="<?php echo CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ?>"/>
```

Comment: you don't need to do it in the code, just define your field in the database to have the current timestamp as the default

Answer (score 3):

```
Use value= <?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); ?>
```

Set the date format as per your need.

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="hidden" name="tstamp" value="<?php echo time(); ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in the backend, just by using a `default value` to the table column.

```
UPDATE <table_name> SET <column_name> = NOW();
```