# How to assign default value current date and time to input field

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

How to assign default value current time stamp  to input field  then i want to insert into db as hidden.

```
  <input
    name="status" id="status"
    type="hidden"
    value="<?php echo CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ?>"
  />
</td> </tr>
```

just tell me how to assign default value (current taimestamp).

because  we can't add columns in db  more than 1 as current time stamp i have already 1 column current time stamp in db table so i need 1 more that's why i want to add as hidden.

Comment: why not just use a date time field in the database and store NOW() on insert or even better use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP default

Comment: @Dave he says he has already a field with current timestamp

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP. How to assign current date and time to an input field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15361510/php-how-to-assign-current-date-and-time-to-an-input-field)

Answer (score 3):

For hidden field you can use php function date()

```
$data['column_name'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$data['other_column1'] = 'other value 1';
$data['other_column2'] = 'other value 2';
$data['other_column3'] = 'other value 3';

$this->db->insert('tabel_name',$data);
```

Comment: But he wants current time stamp

Comment: and date is giving him current time with date.

Comment: Raheel Shan excellent your method works well thanks for response

Comment: You are welcome. But please always do some research before posting questions. The solution by googling are easy to find.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo time();?>" name="my_unique">
```

that's it

Comment: Gautam thanks for quick response i used as you said but it saves time in db table column like this 1363340419 culumn type is a varchar i even used time stamp but same result.

Comment: So you need to specify us about time formate in your DB..??right

Answer (score 0):

you will get current time stamp using : `time();`

So : `<input name="time" type="hidden" value="<?php echo time();?>" >`

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo date("Y/m/d h:i:s a"); ?>
```

is it ok on this input

Comment: As he wants to use it server-side, maybe it would be wiser to use a more simple format to parse (like a timestamp).